# Custom styles for angular pagination

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#getting_started to implement pagination.

I have easily made pagination with

```
<uib-pagination  ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="5" total-items="100" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="5"></uib-pagination>
```

The link generated have  the bootstrap styles applied but I want to apply custom CSS styles for the links generated. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Override the CSS properties you wish to change.
For example

```
.pagination>.active>a {
  background: yellow;
 }
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/guyogev/pen/KXemXg)